# How to define a function the Dirichlet L-function $L(s,\overline{\chi(5,2)})$ in Mathematica?

Tags: special-functions, number-theory

In Mathematica:

The Dirichlet L-function with character $\chi(5,2)$, $L(s,\chi(5,2))$, is expressed as
`DirichletL[5,2,s]`

Let $\overline{\chi(5,2)}$ be the complex conjugate of $\chi(5,2)$. How to define the function $L(s,\overline{\chi(5,2)})$ in Mathematica?

Thanks-
mike

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe by `Conjugate[DirichletL[5, 2, Conjugate[s]]]`?

$$L(\overline{\chi(5,2)}, s) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \overline{\chi(5,2)(n)} \, n^{-s} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \overline{ \chi(5,2)(n) \, \overline{n^{-s}}}$$

and since $n$ is real, we have $\overline{n^{-s}} = n^{-\overline{s}}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It turned out that $\overline{\chi(5,2)(n)}= \chi(5,4)(n)$. So this is workaround. But your answer is definitely much better.

Comment: You're welcome!